# Why does `:cdo print` not show full output?

Tags: quickfix, message

`:cdo print` command (intended to print every line in the quickfix list), shows generic file information instead of line output for some quickfix entries. Why is this?

> The following example is taken from [*Practical Vim*](https://pragprog.com/titles/dnvim2) tip 109 "Call grep Without Leaving Vim". In the [code samples](https://pragprog.com/titles/dnvim2/source_code), the source text files are in the `code/grep` directory.)

In the example, the quickfix list is populated with three entries across two text files:

```
:code/grep
:grep Waldo *
:cli
 1 department-store.txt:1: Waldo is beside the boot counter.
 2 goldrush.txt:6: Waldo is studying his clipboard.
 3 goldrush.txt:9: The penny farthing is 10 paces ahead of Waldo.
```

However, `:cdo print` outputs unexpected text `"goldrush.txt" 9 lines --11%--` for the first entry instead of `Waldo is beside the boot counter.`:

```
(1 of 3): Waldo is beside the boot counter.
"goldrush.txt" 9 lines --11%--
(2 of 3): Waldo is studying his clipboard.
Waldo is studying his clipboard.
(3 of 3): The penny farthing is 10 paces ahead of Waldo.
The penny farthing is 10 paces ahead of Waldo.
```

## Observations

1. The behavior of `:cdo print` is different from that of sister commands `:{tab,arg,buf}do print`, whose output includes all applicable lines, for instance `:bufdo print`:

   ```
   Waldo is beside the boot counter.
   A man has found gold.
   ```
2. Redirecting `:cdo print` to a register shows the *expected* output.

   ```
   :redir @a
   :cdo print
   :redir END
   ```

   A subsequent `:echo @a` reveals:

   ```
   "department-store.txt" 5 lines --20%-- ((2) of 2)
   (1 of 3): Waldo is beside the boot counter.
   Waldo is beside the boot counter.

   "goldrush.txt" 9 lines --11%-- (2 of 2)
   (2 of 3): Waldo is studying his clipboard.
   Waldo is studying his clipboard.
   (3 of 3): The penny farthing is 10 paces ahead of Waldo.
   The penny farthing is 10 paces ahead of Waldo.
   ```

   Compared to this, the direct output of `:cdo print` appears to be truncated.

---

Vim version: 8.2.800

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`:help :cdo`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acdo) explains that the command actually is comprised of several subcommands:

> It works like doing this:
>           :cfirst
>           :{cmd}
>           :cnext
>           :{cmd}
>           etc.

The "truncation" you observe are the file open messages of any new files from the quickfix list; these compete with the `:print` command for the (limited) output area and thus partially overwrite each other. If you don't see the same behavior with `:argdo` et al., this looks like an inconsistency in its implementation. You may want to open an issue at the [bug tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues), or directly discuss this on the [vim_dev mailing list](https://www.vim.org/community.php). The `:cdo` command is a later addition; something might have been missed in its implementation, as it mainly is invoked for the side effects of the supplied `{command}`, and not for the output itself as with `:print`.

**Update**: This inconsistency has been fixed in version 8.2.0836. Thanks Yeggapan for picking this up and supplying a patch!

Comment: I have created pull request https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/6155 to address this.

Comment: Thanks Ingo for the explanation and Yegappan for the PR. Ingo—though the docs state that `:cdo {cmd}` is equivalent to `:cfirst {cmd}`, `:cnext`, `:{cmd}`, etc, they also point out that only _valid_ quickfix entries are used by `:cdo`. `:cfirst`, however, jumps to the first entry, regardless of whether it is valid or not. The way the docs are worded today, this seems a tad misleading, as the two are not completely equivalent. Would it help to adjust the docs?